# Different ROS versions on multiple machines

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I do have a robot that is running ROS Fuerte and I can't upgrade due to compatibility reasons with other systems. I do have a second ROS installation on a PC for visualisation and interface purposes running Fuerte too. The robot is running the roscore.
Now I was thinking about if it is possible to ubgrade my PC to ROS Groovy and use the multi machine feature with different ROS versions.
Will this work and if yes, there any cutbacks?

Best Wishes

Johannes Mayr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76279/different-ros-versions-on-multiple-machines/) by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-09-04**:
@tfoote's answer to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/37403/ros-backwards-compatibility-in-distributed-system/) is also relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer would be yes, it could, but it's not made to be compatible.

AFAIK the low level communication hasn't changed. So, if your systems are on separate machines, there shouldn't be any issues. However, this requires that all messages that you are sending and receiving are exactly the same. This is something that very likely has changed somewhere. So, unless you know that you will always have a limited tested communication, you can make it work. If you set that up long-term, you might find out that the message that you need urgently at some point was changed.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-09-03**:
I think you should emphasize the **[,,] all messages [..] are exactly the same**, and **always have a limited tested communication**. In general this does **not** work, and can lead to very subtle bugs.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-09-04**:
These bugs are not that subtle, system will explicitly tell you that checksums are different and will issue errors immediately. I am using Groovy with Fuerte for a long time without much trouble. So it is really case by case.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-09-04**:
@Boris: yes, the MD5 will be different. However, semantics also matter, as well as the resulting actions of the nodes involved. Those are not captured by a matching MD5.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-04**:
I wouldn't assume that the semantics of the same message changes. If you do, this might also be a problem within the same distribution.

**Comment by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on 2013-09-04**:
OK, thank you for the reply, I will test if it works for my setup and see if I will get errors for the msg I'm using.

**Comment by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on 2013-09-10**:
I tested this now and using rviz on the groovy pc to visualize everything from the fuerte pc works quite fine. The only problem I face is that I can't use "set 2D Nav Goal" from the groovy rviz to send a /goal to my fuerte navigator. Any suggestions?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-10**:
That usually just sends out the message. Maybe the topic changed?

**Comment by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on 2013-09-10**:
I just noticed that none of the published topics from groovy can be passed to fuerte. I just called rostopic pub on an arbitrary topic and did a rostopic echo in fuerte and received nothing

**Comment by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on 2013-09-10**:
Problem solved, this was an issue with an forgotten entry in the /etc/hosts file on the fuerte side. Looking at rxgraph I could see that fuerte can't gain any informations about nodes running on the groovy side which indicates that the communication is not set up fine.

**Comment by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on 2013-09-10**:
So fare I can't notice any problems regarding the compatibility of ROS goovy and ROS fuerte, but I just use basic topics and nodes on the ROS groovy side. If anything occurs I will publish it.

Best Wishes Johannes